# How to Read This Text File and store in a list using C#

Tags: c#, linq

The Text File Data is Like Below:

```
S.No    Name        Description Quantity    Rate    Discount    Amount
1       Apple       Friut is    12      24.02       0           242
                    Good for
                    health
2       Orange      Friut       5       12.22       3           128
3       Banana      Friut       5       12.22       3           128
4       Grapes      Friut       5       12.22       3           128
```

I want to add all the Rows& Columns in list but Description column have multiple Rows in single item. How can I Solve this. I add My Existing Code Here:

My Existing Code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dd = File.ReadAllLines(                    
                "C:\\Users\\Trainee\\Desktop\\Saravanan_Test\\27.8.2018\\Inputfile.txt")
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Where(s => s.Length > 1)
                     .Select(x => splits(x)).ToList();

        foreach (var item in dd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.id+"\t" 
                              + item.Name+"\t"
                              + item.Description+"\t"
                              + item.Quantity+"\t"
                              + item.Rate+"\t"
                              + item.Discount+"\t"
                              + item.Amount);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static Class1 splits(string x)
    {
        var columns = x.Split('\t').Where(c => c != "").ToList();
        return new Class1
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]),
            Name = columns[1],
            Description = columns[2],
            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(columns[3]),
            Rate = Convert.ToDouble(columns[4]),
            Discount = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]),
            Amount = int.Parse(columns[6])
        };
    }
}    

class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store data into list like:

```
list.Add(new{ sno=1, Name="Apple", 
              Description="Friut is good for Health", 
              Quantity=12, Rate=24.02, Discount=0,
              Amount=242 });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you create this file? Is there any chance of changing this file? Its not good format of data. If file format is fixed , kindly share file content here. Image data can not work in copy file content.

Comment: @SARAVANANPONNUSAMY You can use the *edit* link under your original post (OP) to update your question. Please add your file-contents there instead of as a comment. Also a more precise description would be good: Are there tabs in the text file, or are those only regular spaces? Does each column start at an explicitly specified column number?

Comment: I try to add content but it's alignment changed. There are Tabs and reguler some spaces both are placed between columns

Comment: The values are separated by spaces? According to the image of notepad, it seems like the values were separated by spaces. When it is so, you need to create a custom parser. The format is a rather atypical form *(single value in multiple lines; I haven't seems something like this until now)*. But there should be no big problem as long as you know the exact rules of the file.

Comment: Is there  any possible way to send my text file to you?

Comment: This file is very difficult to parse, especially the SNo.1 with that description. Why not just rely on CSV format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This solution is based on the file shared in question. Data is separated by spaces and format is not advisable to use. Answering to help person with content format he has. Tested and working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

    var dd = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test.txt")
     .Skip(1)
     .Where(s => s.Length > 1).ToList();

    foreach (var item in dd)
    {
        var columns = item.Split('\t').Where(c => c.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();

        if (columns != null && columns.Count > 0)
        {
            int id;

            if (int.TryParse(columns[0], out id))
            {
                list.Add(new Data()
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]),
                    Name = columns[1],
                    Description = columns[2],
                    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(columns[3]),
                    Rate = Convert.ToDouble(columns[4]),
                    Discount = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]),
                    Amount = int.Parse(columns[6])
                });
            }
            else
            {
                list.Last().Description += columns[0];
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: bro it's work fine but it only Works for Above format of Input.
if i want to give an input like this,: i changed the text file content in question what can i do?

Comment: @SARAVANANPONNUSAMY my friend, as everybody mentioned in comments and I also mentioned in my answer, your text file is separated by space and there is no pattern in this file for separation. Better, you should use csv format or other stranded format. Writing a parser for this file will take some time because your format is not proper. Hope you understand!

Comment: @ Gaurang Dav bro if we don't  know there is  normal space or tab used for seperate columns, then what will do?

Comment: @SARAVANANPONNUSAMY If you/team are creating this file this file, change it to proper format. Or else, you require to write custom parser for this file by checking all the spaces and tabs. Make it CSV if you can.