# How to reference List<Data>

Tags: c#, list, reference

I am new to C# and I have taken a small task on. The StackOverflow entry for reading a text file and saving to a list is a great start for me. I need to read a text file and send the data to an SQL database.

[How to Read This Text File and store in a list using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089854/how-to-read-this-text-file-and-store-in-a-list-using-c-sharp)

The `Data` in `List<Data> list = new List<Data>();` just keeps staying in red.

How can I stop this please?

I am a PLC engineer and I'm trying to collate data that cannot be handled by PLC. I am just trying to read the file so that I can then show the data in a Grid, with a view to populating the SQL database later.

The text file is held on a remote Linux machine. The collator is a WIndows 10 panel. The SQL can reside on teh Windows panel or remotely.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

    var dd = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test.txt")
     .Skip(1)
     .Where(s => s.Length > 1).ToList();

    foreach (var item in dd)
    {
        var columns = item.Split('\t').Where(c => c.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();

        if (columns != null && columns.Count > 0)
        {
            int id;

            if (int.TryParse(columns[0], out id))
            {
                list.Add(new Data()
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]),
                    Name = columns[1],
                    Description = columns[2],
                    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(columns[3]),
                    Rate = Convert.ToDouble(columns[4]),
                    Discount = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]),
                    Amount = int.Parse(columns[6])
                });
            }
            else
            {
                list.Last().Description += columns[0];
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I just keep receiving red squiggly lines on `<Data`. within Visual Studio

Comment: did you add this using to the top of you code? `using System.Collections.Generic;`
Either you did not import that namespace or `Data` is invalid for some reason

Comment: What error do you get? What is `Data`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Please, *build* the solution; what is the error(s) the compiler shows?

Comment: Where is your class called `Data`?

Comment: You old posted had class Class1.  So either change the list from Data to Class1 or change the class name from Class1 to Data.

Comment: Did you create the Data class?

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work and I read the DAT/text file straight into a DatagridView. I am now writing the Grid to SQL.

Many thanks, sorry for latency as I've been away on-site.

```
            String sLine = "";

            try
            {
                //Pass the file you selected with the OpenFileDialog control to
                //the StreamReader Constructor.
                System.IO.StreamReader FileStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //You must set the value to false when you are programatically adding rows to
                //a DataGridView.  If you need to allow the user to add rows, you
                //can set the value back to true after you have populated the DataGridView
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

                // Clear the DataGridView prior to reading a new text file
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

                //Read the first line of the text file
                sLine = FileStream.ReadLine();
                //The Split Command splits a string into an array, based on the delimiter you pass.
                //I chose to use a semi-colon for the text delimiter.
                //Any character can be used as a delimeter in the split command.
                //string[] s = sLine.Split(';');
                string[] s = sLine.Split('\t');

                //In this example, I placed the field names in the first row.
                //The for loop below is used to create the columns and use the text values in
                //the first row for the column headings.
                for (int i = 0; i <= s.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    DataGridViewColumn colHold = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    colHold.Name = "col" + System.Convert.ToString(i);
                    colHold.HeaderText = s[i].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHold);
                }

                //Read the next line in the text file in order to pass it to the
                //while loop below
                sLine = FileStream.ReadLine();
                //The while loop reads each line of text.
                while (sLine != null)
                {
                    //Adds a new row to the DataGridView for each line of text.
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                    //This for loop loops through the array in order to retrieve each
                    //line of text.
                    for (int i = 0; i <= s.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        //Splits each line in the text file into a string array
                        //s = sLine.Split(';');
                        s = sLine.Split('\t');
                        //Sets the value of the cell to the value of the text retreived from the text file.
                        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[i].Value = s[i].ToString();
                    }
                    sLine = FileStream.ReadLine();
                }
                //Close the selected text file.
                FileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //Display any errors in a Message Box.
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error "+ err.Message, "Program Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```